# Convert a WPF dispatcher to Winforms BGworker?

Tags: wpf, winforms, multithreading, backgroundworker, dispatcher

i recently acquired some source code for a console wrapper for a server. The program was originaly in WPF and part of the code was:

```
private void ServerProc_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ConsoleTextBlock.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
        ConsoleScroll.ScrollToEnd();
    }));
}

private void ServerProc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        ConsoleTextBlock.Text += e.Data + "\r\n";
        ConsoleScroll.ScrollToEnd();
        ParseServerInput(e.Data);
    }));
}
```

Its also had this annotation in both voids:

> // You have to do this through the Dispatcher because this method is
> called by a different Thread

However in WinForms there is no such thing -  is there a way to change this to a Background worker or something (Ive barely done any multi-threading)?

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are event handlers.  Chances are they are from some kind of listening code and I would expect that they are called from a non UI thread (eg normally a threadpool thread that is doing the listening).  You can check that by putting a break point and looking at the threads window in the debugger.
So you will need to apply the winforms way of updating the UI from a non UI thread.
If you search SO you should find quite a lot on how to do that. E.g
[Updating UI from a different thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724972/updating-ui-from-a-different-thread)
[How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

Comment: Thanks, but im not too sure how i can apply this to my code - Im much better with VB.NET, still getting used to C#

Answer (score 1):

Some background: A process that is running in a thread other than the UI thread is not allowed to access any UI controls directly.  Your WPF ServerProc is running in a different thread than your UI which requires the `Dispatcher` to help you communicate from the ServerProc thread back to the UI controls in your UI thread.

If your ServerProc -- in WPF or WinForms -- were running in the UI thread, you would not need to surround it with the `Dispatcher.Invoke` call.

For you, you can put your ServerProc in a [BackgroundWorker (MSDN example)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Your `DoWork` method would contain the meat of the code doing the work and then depending on how the ServerProc does its work, you might be able to use `ProgressChanged` to do what both your sample WPF methods are doing. `ProgressChanged` has a parameter passed in that you would indicate if it were an error or data has been received and inside the function you could display the appropriate info. Take a look at the MSDN docs because they have a good example.

What's important to point out is that `ProgressChanged` happens on the UI thread so you do NOT need to surround your calls to your UI controls with Invoke; just call them normally.  Same goes for `RunWorkerCompleted` which may be the other option for displaying data when your ServerProc has finished its job.

Finally, if you actually had to access a UI control from within your thread, you do something very similar looking as your WPF code sample.  Look at [MethodInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx). Instead of Dispatcher, you're really just calling it from your main Form.

Comment: The problem is both ServerProc methods are event handlers - and will be called by the existing code on a non UI thread.  Im note sure how BackgroundWorker can help in this case?  I dont think he wants to rewrite the existing server-listening/event-firing code - just the event handlers - an there are already on a non UI thread.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! ;D  i used the Method invoker!  No i can finally get this application going. Great help. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexOgden If this provided a solution for you then you should mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the tick at the left.